# Force Login to use APP

Tags: facebook

Force log-in to use my APP? Can I do this like the following example?

When someone not logged in go into your app, eg:
https://apps.facebook.com/gmteste/
They can see your entirely app without login, can I force they to login? eg:
https://apps.facebook.com/ruaevolution/

Also, I didn't found any question answered like this in here. or on Facebook itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the signed_request, and see if it has the oauth_token property set – if so, the user has authorized your app, otherwise not.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/